# Eclipse and java- Method proposal Issues

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, methods, windowbuilder

I use eclipse as an editor and `Java` as a programing language. Usually, when I put `.` after a variable (ex: `Array.`), usually a menu shows up with proposal methods. However,  when I downloaded `WindowBiulder` and `swing libraries`  on Eclipse, whenever I put  `.` after a variable, an error massage opens as shown in the picture.

[image]

I tried to use this method: Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced Select Java Proposal.   I closed the editor and opened it. I closed the project and opened it, but I get the same error massage.

Comment: silly question but did you restart the IDE after installing the plugin?

Comment: Have you installed the **correct version** of WindowBuilder? Did you install through *Help>Install New Software*?

Comment: Yes,I actually restarted my computer 2 times, and I downloaded the latest WIndowBuilder version which is the only one showing to me in the latest releases . My eclipse version is 2020-6 . @AndyThomas

Comment: In *Help>Install New Software,* you installed **SWTDesigner** and **SwingDesigner**, the parts that make up WindowBuilder, right?

Comment: I installed everything starting from SwingDesigner to WindowBuilder XML Core , I also update my all the resources I have

Comment: fixed it: I went to preference> General > keys> restore Default.   Eclipse I updated all packages in Eclipse from : About > Insulation Details > Update @AndyThomas